# Prestashop Installation in Mac using XAMP

Tags: xampp, localhost, prestashop

A problem when installing Prestashop through xampp,in Mac I installed xampp activated first and everything from the control panel. Then I downloaded the latest version of Prestashop. I copied the folder in XAMPP in htdcos. The route would be: xampp / htdocs / prestashop / install. However I prepare to install prestashop I get an error.
And the error is :
 PHP Fatal error: Class 'Tools' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/prestashop/classes/PrestaShopAutoload.php on line 168 Any idea how to fix it? :)

Here are the screenshots attached with error= define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);: and define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false); 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

open */Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/prestashop/classes/PrestaShopAutoload.php* file in line 168 and change `Tools::error_log` on `error_log`.

Then you will see "Cannot write temporary file " message.

Check dir owner and make your */Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/prestashop/cache/* dir writable (recursive) to webserver user, like:
`chown -R someuser /dir` (and may be needed e.g. `chmod 755 /dir` in some cases, depends on your environment)

Comment: You said to take the 168th line of PrestaShopAutoload.php ie,  Tools::error_log('Cannot write temporary file '.$filename_tmp); then  you said to change the Tools::error_log on error_log . Can you please expalin I did not understant.

Comment: Thank you sergii. I solved the problem.I just commented the 168th line of PrestaShopAutoload.php. And gave the full permission ->chmod -R 777 * .And the installation was succesfull.